# Azure Global Administrator can't give permission to application in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have a Sharepoint Online subscription.
According to the Azure portal, I'm a *Global administrator* in the created tenant.

When I try to register an app with the *appinv.aspx form* using the following XML, I can't accept is as I'm not a *Tenant administrator*.

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
  <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="FullControl" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

What can I do about this?

Comment: Commenting since I won't be answering your question, but why are you creating legacy SharePoint Addins and not using the SharePoint Graph API (Sites.FullControl.All) instead? Addin development is deprecated.

Comment: You have a point :) Eventually I created an Azure AD app and used it to access the site.